# Billing simulation

Tags: c#, billing

I need to create a program that asks the client how many items hes going to Bill, then ask for the product name, quantity and price. After that is done it should calculate the total price of all the products and print as a `.txt` file.

I'm stuck in the second step as I'm new to using arrays... here's my code until now (I use Visual Studio 2019):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Final_lab
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) => Factura();

            static void Factura()

            {
            int x;
            Console.WriteLine("Por favor indique la cantidad de registros a ingresar...");
            int cantidad = recibir();
            Console.WriteLine("Por favor indique el nombre del productos, la cantidad y el precio por `favor" +`
                "entre comas ',' ");
            
            Console.ReadLine();
            for (x = 0; x < cantidad; x++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Por favor indique el nombre del productos, la cantidad y el precio por favor" +
                "entre comas ',' ");
                x = recibir();
                int[,] productos;
                productos = new int[, ];

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
            

            private static int recibir()
            {
            int guardar = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            return guardar;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are going the wrong way about it, in general, you'd be much better off using a list and a datatype, something like :-

```
        public record BillingLine(string Product, int Quantity, decimal Price); 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var billingLines = new List<BillingLine>();
            Console.WriteLine("How many?");
            var count = GetInt();
            foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range(0, count))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Product Name?");
                var name = GetString();
                Console.WriteLine("Quantity");
                var quantity = GetInt();
                Console.WriteLine("Price");
                var price = GetDecimal();
                billingLines.Add(new BillingLine(name, quantity,price));
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Total to Bill is {billingLines.Select(l => l.Price*l.Quantity).Sum()}");
        }

        public static int GetInt() => Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        public static string GetString() => Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        public static decimal GetDecimal() => Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
```